# Palette api Android 5 not working well

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, palette

i want do the same as new Google play and change the color of the the controls like this image
[image: Google PLay Android 5]
the problem i tried different colors and i can't get the colors like the Google play, um using the same image as Google play and does not work very well, using the same album i get this result:
[image: music test] seems pretty close, however when i use another album and using the same code it looks different: [image: Music test2] im using the 6 possible colors in the screenshots (in text and background)  im using the next code:

```
Palette.generateAsync(bm,32,new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                try {
                    //Random color, Seekbar
                    // palette.getVibrantSwatch().getRgb();
                    findViewById(R.id.songInfo).setBackgroundColor(palette.getDarkMutedSwatch().getRgb());
                    mTrackName.setBackgroundColor(palette.getVibrantColor(R.color.ics_color));
                    mArtistName.setBackgroundColor(palette.getLightVibrantColor(R.color.call_log_voicemail_highlight_color));
                    mTrackName.setTextColor(palette.getMutedColor(R.color.yellow1));
                    mArtistName.setTextColor(palette.getDarkVibrantSwatch().getRgb());
                    findViewById(R.id.controlHolder).setBackgroundColor(palette.getLightMutedSwatch().getRgb());
                    mAlbum.setImageBitmap(finalBm);


                }catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
```

Comment: What are your expectations?

Comment: looks closer to new Google play music :(